# Is posible to run Netlogo on a remote server?

Tags: linux, netlogo, remote-server

I working with Netlogo for simulate some models, the issue I have is that they take to long to run. I'm trying to use a linux machine I have on digital ocean which is much faster than my local machine, I have installed Netlogo there I'm copied all the files, but I'm not finding a way to run the models with out an user interface.

Is there any option for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sure is possible!

Look for the `netlogo-headless.sh` script.

The BehaviorSpace documentation explains its usage much better than I could:

https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/behaviorspace.html#advanced-usage